# Winforms, multiple tables in one form not being updated to database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net, multiple-tables

I have started a winforms project and am using csharp.   Now the context is that of an ecommerce store and I require a form for reordering product from a supplier.  So on one side of the form I am loading the products, and on the other side of the form I am loading the suppliers, and some other details.

To that point I have managed to load the data and send the order.  However I am trying to save the details of the order to another table ( I named it `supplierOrders` )

I have tried the following syntax:

```
datasetTableAdapters.SupplierOrdersTableAdapter ta;
ta = new datasetTableAdapters.SupplierOrdersTableAdapter();

using (ta)
{
    dataset.supplierOrders.AddSupplierOrdersRow(prodId, suppId, quantityReq, note, DateTime.Now);
}
```

Note: `dataset` refers to the data set I have added to the project using `Add Data Source`.

Here I intended to do `ta.Update()` , but no such method or similar `submitChanges()` etc. are there.

Using this code no data is being inserted into the table.   Can you spot any errors in my code please?  Thanks

Comment: It's not appearing in the UI or it's really not inserted into the `DataSet`?

Comment: No it is not inserted in the database.  If I havent provided enough data somewhere advise me please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, your code only insert a row within the `DataSet`. A `DataSet` is a **disconnected**, datastore agnostic repository. Whatever changes you make in it, it won't be saved into the database until you pass it to a data adapter.

Normally there's a dedicated data adapter for the data source. If for example your database is Sql Server, adapter would be `SqlDataAdapter`. For ODBC, there's `OdbcDataAdapter`. Same goes for Oracle, OleDb, etc... these classes implements the basic `IDbDataAdapter` interface which has the `Update` method as well as `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` properties. The `Update` method takes a `DataSet` instance as a parameter. Internally, the adapter class will call the appropriate command to update each `DataRow` object within your `DataSet` depending on their `RowState` property.

A properly set adapter can push a complete `DataSet` up to the `DataBase` as easily as this:

```
adapter.Update(dataset);
```

In your scenario (you mentionned in comments that you're using typed data adapters), what you have to do is:

```
using (var adapter = new datasetTableAdapters.tablenameTableAdapter())
{
    adapter.Update(dataset);
}
```

You can learn more about data adapters [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The dataset already has a dataadapter, this is done automatically by visual studio I assume.   How can I use the adapter however please? Because when i select the table I want  (`datasetTableAdapters.tablenameTableAdapter`), the only two methods that come up are: `equals` and `reference equals`

Comment: @user2151973 I take it that you are using typed dataadapters that are generated with the dataset designer? In any case they work like normal adapters, only they're all set up by default. Just instantiate one and call its `Update` method. See my edited answer.

Comment: i am getting the following error however `is a type that cannot be used in this context`.  I have also generated an ADO.NET entity model, named it `DatabaseContext`, and created an object of `SupplierOrder`.  Funnily enough I can reference to `SupplierOrder` but not to the `DatabaseContext`.

Comment: @user2151973 Please edit your original question and show your faulting code. As for Entity Framework, if you have trouble with that you should post another question on SO.